# Error configuring Coherence Cache on Oracle Weblogic server 10.3.4

Tags: caching, weblogic, portal, oracle-coherence

I'm trying to configure Coherence 3.7 on Oracle Web Logic Server 10.3.4, but when I try to run application on server using eclipse, I get following error.

> <9 May, 2012 4:28:23 PM IST>    with ID '1336561103127' for task '14'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: No storage-enabled nodes exist >for service DistributedSessions'
>   weblogic.application.ModuleException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activateContexts(WebAppModule.java:1497)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.activate(WebAppModule.java:438)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:375)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:95)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   Caused By: com.tangosol.net.RequestPolicyException: No storage-enabled nodes exist for service DistributedSessions
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.o>nMissingStorage(PartitionedCache.CDB:32)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.s>endStorageRequest(PartitionedCache.CDB:11)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.a>ddIndex(PartitionedCache.CDB:11)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$ViewMap.add>Index(PartitionedCache.CDB:1)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.addIndex(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> <9 May, 2012 4:28:23 PM IST>     
>   <9 May, 2012 4:28:23 PM IST>    application '_auto_generated_ear_'.> 
>   <9 May, 2012 4:28:23 PM IST>    nMissingStorage(PartitionedCache.CDB:32)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.s>endStorageRequest(PartitionedCache.CDB:11)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$BinaryMap.a>ddIndex(PartitionedCache.CDB:11)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.daemon.queueProcessor.service.grid.partitionedService.PartitionedCache$ViewMap.add>Index(PartitionedCache.CDB:1)
>       at com.tangosol.coherence.component.util.SafeNamedCache.addIndex(SafeNamedCache.CDB:1)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
> > 

I've checked with the cache start script and enabled local-storage true in it, but it still doesn't works.
Can someone please provide me right steps to configure coherence cache on the Weblogic Server (in web console and in applcation), or suggest me possible reasons why am I getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can happen in a few different cases.  Either the storage-enabled nodes are not connected to the storage-disabled nodes (WebLogic in your case) or the storage-enabled nodes don't have SESSION local storage enabled.  Confirm that the cluster includes the storage-enabled nodes at runtime and confirm that the cache server is started with the following option:

`-Dtangosol.coherence.session.localstorage=true`

Comment: @ Jeff thanks for reply. I've already added this parameter in the cache server run script, but no success.
It would be great if you can provide me quick steps to configure Coherence cache on Weblogic Server including changes that need to made on the server console as well as in the Project

Comment: If you add this parameter to your WebLogic startup script then it should work without a problem.  This will store Coherence data in the same heap as WebLogic.

Comment: @Jeff Did you mean the tangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage property?

Comment: Nope - http://coherence.oracle.com/display/COH35UG/Coherence*Web+Cache+Configuration

Comment: Thanks .. this works - My scenario - a simple mockup with glassfish+(coherence jar in classpath)+External coherence server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify some JVM parameters in your Weblogic Server Installation.  Go to Enviroment-> Servers and select your server. In tab Configuration select the tab Starting Server and fill the field Arguments whit the following JVM parameters

```
-Dtangosol.coherence.cacheconfig=session-cache-config.xml -Dtangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage=true -Dtangosol.coherence.session.localstorage=true 
-Dtangosol.coherence.cluster=CoherenceCluster 
-Dtangosol.coherence.clusteraddress=231.1.3.4 
-Dtangosol.coherence.clusterport=7744
```

This worked for me, I had exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Both localstorage system parameters where set to true. The problem was that my cache configuration was not loading so the requested cache service was simply unknown to that "server" node.

So if you encounter this problem, check if your cache config is being loaded ("Loaded cache configuration from ...").